# How can i return the the OpenCV Frame from my multithreaded camera code to be shown in Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, flask, camera

I am making a Flask application to stream 4 camera webcam feeds at once using multithreading based on some code i copied. How can i return the captured camera frame from gen_frames() to display on my website through return Response() below

```
@camera.route('/video_feed0')
def video_feed0():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    thread0.start()
    return Response(thread0.run(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Full Code here:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, Response
import cv2
import threading

camera = Blueprint('camera', __name__)

class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, previewName, camID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewName = previewName
        self.camID = camID
        
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewName)
        gen_frames(self.previewName, self.camID)
        yield gen_frames()
        
def gen_frames(previewName, camID):  # generate frame by frame from camera
    camerafeed = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)
    camerafeed.set(3, 640)
    camerafeed.set(4, 480)
    print('opening camera 0')
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = camerafeed.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success or camerafeed is None:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result

thread0 = camThread("Camera 0", 0)
thread1 = camThread("Camera 1", 1)
thread2 = camThread("Camera 2", 2)
thread3 = camThread("Camera 3", 3)
            
@camera.route('/camerafeed')
def cameraindex():
    return render_template('camera.html')

@camera.route('/video_feed0')
def video_feed0():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    thread0.start()
    return Response(thread0.run(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@camera.route('/video_feed1')
def video_feed1():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    thread1.start()
    return Response(thread1.run(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@camera.route('/video_feed2')
def video_feed2():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    thread2.start()
    return Response(thread2.run(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@camera.route('/video_feed3')
def video_feed3():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    thread3.start()
    return Response(thread3.run(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: browse these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask+opencv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the individual feed to the webpage, you can do it inside an img tag in your html page like below:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed0') }}"/>
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed1') }}"/>
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed2') }}"/>
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed3') }}"/>
```

Comment: Apologies, might not have explained my question well, what i meant was what can i put into my `return Response( whattoputhere , mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')`  so that i can display the camera feed in my html page

Comment: thread0.run() is not working?